# Use server time when setting timestamp in Entity in Spring

Tags: spring, jpa

I have an entity which has an attribute private LocalDateTime testedAt;

So now if the entity was completely tested I want to set a timestamp .

If I use some of the java functions I think it would use my local time. But instead it should better use the server time.

So whenever I call the method setTestedAt(LocalDateTime timestamp), it should set the time by using the server time. How can I do that in spring jpa.

Comment: Err, the Java code modifying the JPA entities runs on the server, doesn't it? That said, it should be an Instant, not a LocalDateTime.

Comment: I never heard of Instant class before and do not know the difference to LocalDateTime. But ok. So in your opinion I should use Instant class . Instant instant = Instant.now(); gives me UTC time.

Comment: No. It gives you an Instant, i.e. a point of the absolute time line. You can choose to transform this Instant to a ZonedDateTime using whichever time zone you want, and the to transform this ZoendDateTime to a string using any format you want.

Comment: I think LocalDateTime will be fine with me. Instant just stores Greenwich Mean time. That does not help me without converting it do my time zone. In this case I just use LocalDateTime.